# Change value of checkbox in Retool

Tags: javascript, sql, retool

How do I change the value of a checkbox in Retool?

It defaults to true/false but I want to change the default to "cat/dog"

I've tried the below code in the "default value" of the component but its not changing the output value to cat/dog

```
{{checkbox1.value == "false" ? "cat" : "dog"}}
```

Comment: To clarify the issue, I would not suggest binding "cat" or "dog" values for the checkbox1.value.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try to run this code but give it a try; your issue can be a type problem because of `checkbox1.value == "false"`. Try to run your code block as in the following example.

```
{{checkbox1.value ? "dog" : "cat"}}
```

Also, try to bind a default value to `checkbox1.value` as `true` or `false`.